# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not type

Tags: python, matrix, graph, types, shortest-path

I'm implementing a breadth-first search algorithm in Python using adjacency matrices.

By some reason, I'm getting an error I don't why it's appearing.
My code is the next:

```
import numpy as np

# Matrix creation.
n = int(input("Enter n, the dimension of the adjacency matrix: "))
M = np.zeros(shape=(n, n))

# Matrix filling.
print("Insert the matrix elements, representing the edges joining nodes: ")
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        M[i][j] = int(input("M[{}][{}]= ".format(i, j)))
print("\n The matrix is: \n {} \n".format(M))


print("Insert two nodes to compute the shortest path between them. Remember that the nodes are labed from zero to {}: \n".format(n))
a = int(input("First node: "))
b = int(input("Second node: "))

# Queue of visiting nodes. The first element is the starting node.

q = [a]

# Array for visited nodes. The element corresponding to the starting node is marked as visited.

vis = [False] * n
vis[a] = True

# Array of the previous node for the ith node. It starts empty, and of size n.
prev = [int] * n

# Loop to fill the prev array for all nodes. It runs until the queue is empty.
while q:
    # The ith node is the queue front.
    node = q[0]
    adj = M[node]
    q.pop(0)

    # Checks all connections from the ith node.
    for i in range(n):
        if adj[i] != 0:
            if not vis[i]:
                # If a connection is found, it's added to the queue, marked as visited and saved in memory in prev.
                q.append(i)
                vis[i] = True
                prev[i] = node

# Backwards path.

bw = []


#
i = b
while i is not None:
        bw.append(i)
        i = prev[i]

# Path array creation

w = len(bw)
path = [int] * w

# Filling of the path, from the information of the backwards one.

for i in range(w):
    aux = bw[i]
    j = w-1-i
    path[j] = aux

if path[0] == a:
    print("\nThe shortest path between the node {} and the node {} is {},\n".format(a, b, path))
else:
    print("\nThere's not a path between {} and {} :(\n".format(a, b))
```

The error is the next:

```
    i = prev[i]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not type
```

Why can't I make `i = prev[i]` if `prev[i]` an array of integers??

I tried to typecast i with `i = int(prev[i])` but it didn't work.
And now I don't know what to do.
Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: What sense is `prev = [int] * n` supposed to make? You want n copies of the same 1-element array containing a reference to the type int!?

Comment: If, for example, you want a list of 4 ints, all initialized to zero, then you can use: `arr = [0] * 4`.

Comment: @luk2302 it's supposed to store the previous node of the i-th node. For example, if my node is ```i=3``` and there's and edge from node 5 to node 3, then this information will by coded such that ```prev[3] == 5 ``` is true.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the line:

```
prev = [int] * n
```

You're creating a list containing the type int itself. Should be `[0]*n` or something similar.
I'm actually not sure why you're not making an empty list: `prev = []`